# Path labels in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

I am using Google Earth Pro 7.1 and I would like to add labels to my paths so that when I print a map the trails are labeled.

I want to have similar text as placemarks on each of my paths. I do not want to place a placemark at all of the trails. If I can edit the kml to do this I can.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a label to a path in Google Earth, create a placemark where you want the label then set the icon style to show no icon.

When creating/editing the placemark in Google Earth, click on the icon button (shows the default yellow pushpin) to the right of the name. This opens a dialog with a list of icons - click the button "No Icon" then "OK".

Your KML would look something like this:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name>...</name>
        <Style>
          <IconStyle>              
            <Icon>
                <href/>
            </Icon>
          </IconStyle>    
        </Style>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>...</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

***UPDATE***

Alternatively, if you programatically create your KML, you can define a MultiGeometry with a Line and a Point. The label will appear at the location of the Point.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>label line</name>
            <Style>
                <IconStyle>
                    <Icon>
                        <href/>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <MultiGeometry>
                <LineString>
                    <extrude>1</extrude>
                    <coordinates>-82.15035277759922,29.64538384684089 -81.20130342971596,26.99631684790986</coordinates>
                </LineString>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-81.61652196717148,28.47016380668426</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </MultiGeometry>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```